# Hide/show element if input has value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide or show an element based on if an input field has a value. Right now I have this, but the issue here is that it will add `visible` class every time a key is pressed and the value is not empty. Which is not correct and will lead to many problems down the line.

Is there a built in JavaScript event that I can use to check if the element is empty or not? What is the best way to do this with using the least amount of resources?

```
const query_input = document.getElementsByClassName("query")[0];

query_input.addEventListener('input', event => {

    if (query_input.value == ""){

        document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0].classList.add("hidden");

        console.log ("empty");
    }else{
        console.log ("not empty");

        document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0].classList.add("visible");
    }

});
```

Comment: Another way to simpify this is to drop the `visible` class. Elements are visible by default. You only need a `hidden` class with `.hidden { display: none }`. Add the class to hide an element and just remove it to show it again

Answer (score 2):

*I think there is no such built-in thing.*

You can do some improvement:

```
const query_input = document.querySelector(".query");
let btn = document.querySelector(".submit");
query_input.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (query_input.value.trim() == ""){
    btn.classList.remove("visible");//remove
    btn.classList.add("hidden");    //add
    console.log ("empty");
  }else{
    console.log ("not empty");
    btn.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove
    btn.classList.add("visible");   //add
  }

});
```

Comment: Trim is a good call.